# How to get the value of a node using for each and if in xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am new to xpath .. I want to extract all the values of Age which is greater than 24 using for-each and if condition in xslt.

```
 <PriceBooking>
              <Guest>
              <GuestCount Age="24" Code="10" Quantity="1"/>
              <GuestCount Age="26" Code="10" Quantity="1"/>
              <GuestCount Age="3" Code="10" Quantity="1"/>
           </Guest>
    </PriceBooking>
```

So far I tried with the following :-

```
    <xsl:for-each select="PriceBooking/Guest">
    <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="PriceBooking/Guest/GuestCount/@Age &gt; '28'">

    <Age><xsl:value-of select="PriceBooking/Guest/GuestCount/@Age"/></Age>
    </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<Sid>Failed to load</Sid>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

It's always going to otherwise condition .. Please help me with the xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to understand that the `for-each` changes the context node to be a `Guest` element and that way inside you need a relative path e.g.

```
<xsl:when test="GuestCount/@Age > 28">...</xsl:when>
```

But the sample you have posted has `@Age` values 24, 26, and 3 so the condition is never true.